# Hibernate onetomany manytoone issue

Tags: java, json, hibernate

I'm using hibernate as ORM. And I have two entities `Shop` and `TypeShop`. `TypeShop` may have a few shops.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "shop_types")
public class TypeShop {
    ...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="typeShop", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Shop> shops;
    ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "shops")
public class Shop {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "shop_type_id")
    private TypeShop typeShop;
    ...
}
```

When i want to find all `shops` by `TypeShop` `id` in json format i get something like this:

```
[{"id":146,"name":"First Name","address":"First Address","description":"First Description","coordinates":"59.842055288480076, 29.700164794921875","contacts":"First Contacts","site":"First web site","mail":"First email","photos":[],"typeShop":{"id":11,"name":"Производство газобетона","shops":[{"id":146,"name":"First Name","address":"First Address","description":"First Description","coordinates":"59.842055288480076, 29.700164794921875","contacts":"First Contacts","site":"First web site","mail":"First email","photos":[],"typeShop":{"id":11,"name":"Производство газобетона","shops":[{"id":146,"name":"First Name","address":"First Address","description":"First Description","coordinates":"59.842055288480076, 29.700164794921875","contacts":"First Contacts","site":"First web site","mail":"First email","photos":[],"typeShop":{"id":11,"name":"Производство газобетона","shops":[{"id":146,"name":"First Name","address":"First Address","description":"First Description","coordinates":"59.842055288480076, 29.700164794921875","contacts":"First Contacts","site":"First web site","mail":"First email","photos":[],"typeShop":{"id":11,"name":"Производство газобетона","shops":[{"id":146,"name":"First Name","address":"First Address","description":"First Description","coordinates":"59.842055288480076, 29.700164794921875","contacts":"First Contacts","site":"First web site","mail":"First email","photos":[],"typeShop":{"id":11,"name":"Производство газобетона","shops":[{"id":146,"name":"First Name","address":"First Address","description":"First Description","coordinates":"59.842055288480076, 29.700164794921875","contacts":"First Contacts","site":"First web site","mail":"First email","photos":[],"typeShop":{"id":11,"name":"Производство газобетона","shops":[{"id":146,"name":"First Name","address":"First Address","description":"First Description","coordinates":"59.842055288480076, 29.700164794921875","contacts":"First Contacts","site":"First web site","mail":"First email","photos":[],"typeShop":{"id":11,"name":"Производство газобетона","shops":[{"id":146,"name":"First Name","address":"First Address","description":"First Description","coordinates":"59.842055288480076, 29.700164794921875","contacts":"First Contacts","site":"First web site","mail":"First email","photos":[],"typeShop":{"id":11,"name":"Производство газобетона","shops":[{"id":146,"name":"First Name","address":"First Address","description":"First Description","coordinates":"59.842055288480076, 29.700164794921875","contacts":"First Contacts","site":"First web site","mail":"First email","photos":[],"typeShop":{"id":11,"name":"Производство газобетона","shops":[{"id":146,"name":"First Name","address":"First Address","description":"First Description","coordinates":"59.842055288480076, 29.700164794921875","contacts":"First Contacts","site":"First web site","mail":"First email","photos":[],"typeShop":{"id":11,"name":"Производство газобетона","shops":[{"id":146,"name":"First Name","address":"First Address","description":"First .....
```

And the list goes on again and again. As you can see because of fetch type `EAGER` I get an infinite json format. I've tried to change `EAGER` to `LAZY` but i got `“failed to lazily initialize a collection of role” exception`.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

**EDITED:**
It helps if i remove getter for `TypeShop` from `Shop` entity. But i'm curious if there is better way.

Answer (score 0):

This is called JSON bi directional reference problem. Refere : http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBiDirReferences

Check **[@JsonIdentityInfo](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureObjectIdentity) and the @JsonBackReference/@JsonManagedReference**

Annotate your entities with

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
```

should solve your problem.